# Why does View Source and Find in source in IE 11 not working?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

IN IE 11 when I view source and then try searching in the source IE scrolls all over the place and doesn't properly highlight the find results. Anyone else see this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but couldn't resolve it. However, F12 developer options --> Debugger can help you view the source of the page. If developer options didn't work too then, installing below security update should fix it.

For 32 bit system: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45134

For 64 bit system: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45154